# Combining two commands into one and exporting to csv file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Below is the code I'm using get data from the output of two commands, I then put them into two separate array's. When I combine the arrays the output looks how I would expect, but when I do select and try to output, it has gaps and not formatted correct. How get I get this to output nice to a csv file?

Example code:

```
   $a = get-agentserver
$NewCSV = $a | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object PSObject -Prop @{
        'Client Name' = ($_."Name" -Split '\.(?!\d)')[0]
        'Policy Type' = $_."AgentServerType"
    'Backup State' = $_."BackupStatus"
    'logon' = $_."LogonAccountTestStatus"
    'account' = $_."LogonAccount"
            }
} | Select "Client Name","Policy Type","Backup State","logon","account"
#$NewCSV

$l = foreach($i in $a.name){
get-definition -agentserver $i}
$l | convertto-csv | out-file t1.csv
$m = import-csv t1.csv | select agentserver,name,selectionsummary
$defcsv = $m | foreach-object{
    new-object psobject -prop @{
        'Policy Name' = $_.Name
        'Backup Selection' = $_.selectionsummary
        }
} | select "Policy Name","Backup Selection"
#$defcsv

$hope = $NewCSV + $defcsv
$hope2 = $hope | select  "Client Name","Policy Name","Policy Type","Backup Selection"
$hope2
```

Ex output $hope(that look right to me)

```
Client Name  : Name
Policy Type  : Ndmp
Backup State : Unknown
logon        : Succeeded
account      : ndmp_user

Policy Name      : Diff Bakcup 
Backup Selection : COMMON, D: (Partial)
```

Ex output of $hope2(which is killing me how to fix)

```
Client Name                   Policy Name                                     Policy Type Backup Selection
-----------                   -----------                                     ----------- ----------------
Name                                                                              Windows
Name                                                                              Windows
Name                                                                              Windows
Name                                                                              Windows
Name                                                                              Windows
Name                                                                              Ndmp
                              Diff Bakcup - Name       ,...                               COMMON, D: (Partial)
                              ArchiveJob_Backup_to_Tape                                   Name  \e$ (Partial), ...
                              Diff Bakcup - Name       ,...                               COMMON, D: (Partial)
                              ArchiveJob_Backup_to_Tape                                   Name\e$ (Partial), ...
                              Diff Bakcup - Name       ,...                               COMMON, D: (Partial)
                              Name Backup BLR_Pro...                                      /root_vdm/IN-BLR400-FS-C...
```

I have cleaned up my code and tried to put my command outputs into one variable and iterate through it in one go, which looks much nicer, but the output result in the same as above in my $hope2 output. It is leaving a big gap under two of the header "Policy Name" and "Backup Selection". Is there a way to use regex to remove those particular spaces only under those two columns in Powershell?

This is the new code I am running using

```
$agentserver = get-agentserver
$agentserver | convertto-csv | select-object -skip 2 | out-file t2.csv
$agentserver = import-csv t2.csv -Header server,id,type,accountstate,logonaccount
$budefinition = foreach($i in $a.name){
get-backupdefinition -agentserver $i}
$budefinition | convertto-csv | out-file t1.csv
$converted_budef = import-csv t1.csv | select agentserver,name,selectionsummary
$a = $agentserver + $converted_budef
$NewCSV = $a | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object PSObject -Prop @{
        'Client Name' = ($_."server" -Split '\.(?!\d)')[0]
        'Policy Type' = $_."type"
    'Backup State' = $_."BackupStatus"
    'logon' = $_."LogonAccountTestStatus"
    'account' = $_."LogonAccount"
    'Policy Name' = ($_.Name -replace ","," ")
    'Backup Selection' = ($_.selectionsummary -replace ","," ")
                    }
} | Select "Client Name","Policy Name","Policy Type","Backup Selection"
$NewCSV
```

Example of what I am trying to accomplish would look like this, that I can then use the export-csv and have a nice csv doc.

```
Client Name Policy Name Policy Type Backup Selection
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------
NAME         Diff Bakup Windows     Common D
NAME         Archive    Ndmp        /root_vdm/
```

After doing $NewCSV | fl I get a output of two separate list as shown below and I need them to all be in one. Any ideas how to fix it in my code above?

```
Client Name      : Name
Policy Name      :
Policy Type      : Ndmp
Backup Selection :

Client Name      :
Policy Name      : Diff Bakcup 
Policy Type      :
Backup Selection : COMMON  D: (Partial)
```

Comment: You shouild choose better variable names, $a=$AgentServers , $l=BackupDefinitions, $m a stripped down version of that, What properties shall defcsv get? Join arrays doesn't work the way you tried. I'd nest the iterations and build the desired final outcome in one go.

Comment: @LotPings Ok thank you, sorry if I use the wrong terminally, maybe combine is a better word, the result of $hope has all the data I want to export out to csv. I will try to nest the $defcsv code into the $NewCsv code and see how it turns out. The porperties of defcsv are getting the properties I need, 'Policy Name', and 'Backup Selection' (unless this is not what you mean by properties). Thanks again

Comment: What do you get from $hope2 | fl ?

Comment: @WalterMitty I am trying to get the final result to be in a nice format that I can do a export-csv and create a csv document.

Comment: @WalterMitty I ran my output through the | fl. I see what you mean, it looks to be two seperated list. one list has some entry's missing and the other this has those entry's but has the other two missing. I will post my an example above. Any idea how to correct it?

Comment: When you combine the two arrays, are you trying to get the same result as with a relational equijoin?  Is there a common field in the two arrays that could link matching entries together?  Btw, relational equijoin is not powershell jargon.

Comment: @WalterMitty I'm not trying to do a equijoin. I have two seperate cli cmd I'm running. I extract the data from what I need out of them. In $hope I have all the data that I need. I'm trying to then put this data into an array manipulate the data and out-put it. As you pointed out when I run fl which I'm now using $NewCsv I can see its not combining them properly. I don't understand how to get it to work properly. I'm thinking I need to correct something before I put it into an array or maybe I don't even need an array. I'm heading down rabbit hole here.

Comment: In the new code you are running, there is an error on line 4.  You reference $a before assigning a value to it.